# Ionic 4 native Device plugin returns device uuid null on platform browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

By running `ionic cordova run browser` device uuid is null as Device object is empty on browser platform.

Device info should be there as it supports browser platform like

`platform: browser`
`uuid: "someid"`

Here's my code:

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';

constructor(private device: Device) { }

console.log('Device UUID is: ' + this.device.uuid);
```

Result: `Device UUID is: null`

I'm using `@ionic-native/device": "^5.5.0`

Please help me out how to resolve this problem. I have tested the code on android device. It's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly the `device.uuid` property is not supported on the browser platform. See the supported platforms [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#deviceuuid).

So you might want to check the [`device.platform`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#deviceplatform) beforhand and handle the browser platform differently something like this:

```
if (this.device.platform === 'browser') {
  console.log('Device UUID is not supported on browser platform');
} else {
  console.log('Device UUID is: ' + this.device.uuid);
}
```